# Wallpaper and thumbnails trouble after deleting two hidden desktop.ini files on my desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop.ini

On Windows 7 I have deleted two hidden `desktop.ini` files on my desktop, and now I have a problem with my wallpaper and my thumbnails in my system. How can I fix it?

Comment: you can see more details here: [Is it Safe to Delete Desktop.ini Files From my Desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/84593/is-it-safe-to-delete-desktop-ini-files-from-my-destkop)

Comment: I have deleted the desktop.ini files

Comment: Regarding *two* desktop.ini files on the desktop: a detailed example is in *[What are the desktop.ini files for?](http://superuser.com/questions/307020/what-are-the-desktop-ini-files-for)*.

Answer (score 1):

I made an empty file called `desktop.ini`, and it solved it.